# How do I rate songs on the 5th gen iPod nano?

Tags: itunes, ipod-nano

How do I rate songs on the 5th generation iPod nano?  Is it possible?  Do they get copied back to iTunes?

Answer (score 7):

The 5th Gen nano still had a click wheel, so you should just have to click the center button twice, and then turn the click wheel left or right to adjust ratings. And yes, these should sync back to iTunes.